# need help comparing dates in access via vba

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

I have following problem: Can't get sql query to work with dates. Following query:

```
strRowSource = "SELECT [ID],[TaskType],[TaskName],[StartDate],[EndDate],[isFinished] " & _
"FROM tblTasks " & "WHERE [Person] = " & TempVars("CurrentUser") & " AND [EndDate] < #" & Format(Now(), "short date") & "#"
```

Doesn't return any value. what im trying to get is task list which are overdue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: nope doesn't work. im pulling my hairs off and already tried tens of different approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this handy function to format dates:

```vb
Public Function JetSqlDate(ByVal d As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(d) Then
        JetSqlDate = "NULL"
    Else
        JetSqlDate = Format$(d, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
strRowSource = "SELECT ID, TaskType, TaskName, StartDate, EndDate, isFinished " & _
  "FROM tblTasks WHERE Person = " & TempVars("CurrentUser") & _
  " AND EndDate < " &  JetSqlDate(Now())
```

Note that escaping column names (`[]`) is only required when they contain invalid characters like spaces or when they conflict with  keywords. E.g. if you had a column named `From` you would have to write it as `[From]`.

---

for SQL-Server pass-through queries I use:

```vb
Public Function TSqlDate(ByVal d As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(d) Then
        TSqlDate = "NULL"
    Else
        TSqlDate = "{ ts '" & Format$(d, "yyyy\-mm\-dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "' }"
    End If
End Function
```

For strings:

```vb
Public Function SqlStr(ByVal s As String) As String
'Input: s=""      Returns: NULL
'Input: s="abc"   Returns: 'abc'
'Input: s="x'y"   Returns: 'x''y'

    If s = "" Then
        SqlStr = "NULL"
    Else
        SqlStr = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
End Function
```

Note that this functions adds the delimiters and escapes any delimiters contained in the string value. This makes queries more reliable and also prevents [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: Perfect Olivier - it does indeed work :) tyvm

Comment: I wanted to upvote the answer but for that at least 15 rep is needed. Accepted the answer with checkmark though. Thanks for explaining me how things works here

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce it to:

```vb
strRowSource = "SELECT ID, TaskType, TaskName, StartDate, EndDate, isFinished " & _
    "FROM tblTasks " & _
    "WHERE Person = " & TempVars("CurrentUser") & " AND EndDate < Now()"
```